# Is there a translator library from Access syntax SQL to T-SQL available for C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-access

Obviously built-in database functions won't be the same, which is why I'm avoiding their use, but is there a general parser available that could read in Access SQL commands?

Even if they don't turn into T-SQL for me automatically, but some kind of container object where I could identify the type of command and the the columns being updated/inserted, the WHERE conditions, etc.

I know this isn't the best way to do it, but I've inherited it.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to find much, but there is an old project on CodeProject:

[Jet to SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sqljet.aspx)

If that doesn't work for you and you can't find a utility, here is a conversion cheat-sheet:

[Jet SQL to T-SQL Cheatsheet](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/Quick-Access-JET-SQL-to-T-SQL-Cheatsheet.aspx)